# check more than one string in strtotime

Tags: php, strtotime

I have this code to check if the mysql timestamp is 24 hours old, it works for one string however I need to check two strings but i'm not sure how to add it in

```
if(strtotime($dateFrom." + 24 hours") <= strtotime("now"))
```

for example i'd like to add the string in

```
if(strtotime($dateFrom **&& $dateTo.**" + 24 hours") <= strtotime("now"))
```

Comment: That doesn't really make sense .. which timestamp has to be 24 hours old?  The "From" or the "To?"

Comment: You dont have the right approach to this. Anyways, when comparing time I always try my best to stick to Unix timestamps. Then you can do $ts - (60 * 60 * 24); for 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(strtotime($dateFrom." + 24 hours") <= strtotime("now") && 
       strtotime($dateTo." + 24 hours") <= strtotime("now"))
```

Comment: `time();` runs 30x faster than `strtotime("now");` and returns the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( strtotime($dateFrom + "24 hours") <= strtotime("now") &&
    strtotime($dateTo + "24 hours")   <= strtotime("now"))
```

OR

```
if( strtotime($dateFrom + "24 hours") <= strtotime("now") ||
    strtotime($dateTo + "24 hours")   <= strtotime("now"))
```